# General term of the sequence related

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is general term of the following sequence?

$$n = 1\; 2\; 3\; 4\; 5\; 6\; 7\; 8\; 9\; 10\; 11\; 12\; 13\; 14\; 15\; 16\; 17\; 18\; 19\; 20\; 21\; 22\; 23\; 24\; 25\; 26\; 27\; 28\; 29\; 30 $$

$$f(n) = \;2 \;2 \;2 \;4\; 4\; 4\; \;6\; 6\; 6\; \;8\; 8\; 8\; 10\; 10\; 10\; 12\; 12\; 12\; 14\; 14\; 14\; 16\; 16\; 1\;6 18\; 18\; 18\; 20\; 20\; 20$$

I don't have any idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general term could be $f(n)=2\cdot \left\lfloor \dfrac{n+2}{3}\right\rfloor$, where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ represents the floor function (greatest integer that is less than or equal to $x$)

Answer (score 1):

$f(3k+1) = f(3k+2) = f(3k+3) = 2(k+1), k \geq 0$

Comment: I don't understand actually what you want to say.

Comment: Say you want to know $n$-th term of $f(n)$. First, you write $n$ in the form of $3k+1$, then the value of $f(n)$ is $2(k+1)$

Comment: From this, you can easily obtain the result in user27454's answer.